# Use integers from CSV file to initialize corresponding integers

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm working on a text based game to run out of the Command Prompt that simulates Decking in Shadowrun.  Ideally, the player should be able to have a CSV file (65 rows, 2 columns) with all the character's pertinent information, and that information should be able to be uploaded into the program.

I am at the point where the csv file is properly loaded and displays everything correctly, while still in the loop.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the values out of the loop and into something that I can use to set the values of the various character stats.  Snippets of my code are as follows:

```
public class Program {
static int[][] Character = new int[65][2];

public static void main (String[]args) {
  Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String DeckerName;
  System.out.println("What is your name? (Name of your .csv file)"); //Load Decker character
  DeckerName = user_input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Alright, " + DeckerName + ".  Jacking into the Matrix now...");

  String csvFile = "FILE LOCATION";
  BufferedReader br = null;
  String line = "";
  String cvsSplitBy = ",";
  Scanner loader = new Scanner(System.in);

//Opens and loads .csv file into an array      
  try {
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String characterload[] = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    System.out.println ("" + characterload[0] + ": " + characterload[1]); // for testing purposes, characterload[0] is a text description, characterload[1] is an integer
    int intDeckerProgram = Integer.parseInt(characterload[1]);
    System.out.println(intDeckerProgram); //for testing purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < characterload.length; i++)
    {
      Character[i][1] = intDeckerProgram;
      System.out.println(Character[i][1]); //for testing purposes
    }
   }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (br!= null) {
      try {
        br.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  int DeckerDetectionFactor = Character[0][1];
  System.out.println(Character[0][1]); //for testing purposes
  System.out.println(DeckerDetectionFactor); //for testing purposes
  int DeckerHackingPool = Character[1][1];
  System.out.println(Character[1][1]); //for testing purposes
  System.out.println(DeckerHackingPool); //for testing purposes
```

TL;DR without downloading other java packages, how can I bring the values imported into the characterload array, and put them into the Character array so that my integers are properly initialized?  Thank you for your time, I truly appreciate it!

Edit: The two values at the bottom, DeckerDetectionFactor and DeckerHackingPool, need to be 6 and 9, respectively (this info being drawn from the CSV file).  I am looking for a little direction on how to ensure these values are properly loaded into the Character[][] array so the variables are initialized properly instead of being put at 0.

Comment: On initial glance your code seems to be doing what you want, so are you facing any errors?

Comment: Not errors in the strictest sense, but the two values at the bottom, DeckerDetectionFactor and DeckerHackingPool, need to be 6 and 9, respectively (from the CSV).  With my code as written, they end up returning the values of 0.  I suppose I am looking for a little direction in how to ensure Character[][] is the value it needs to be outside of the loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a review of working code and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perfectly fair - my apologies for posting it in an incorrect area!  And I thought I had voted it solved, but apparently not.  Thank you for bringing that to light!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some helpful advice as given, I ended up removing the inner For loop from the While loop.  Setting up a row integer followed by incrementing that solved the whole issue.  If it helps anyone, here is the code I am using now:

```
...
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
   int row = 0;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String characterload[] = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    int intDeckerProgram = Integer.parseInt(characterload[1]);
      Character[row][1] = intDeckerProgram;
      row++;
   }
...
```